# Store visual studio git credentials on a temp file

Tags: git, visual-studio

**This is how I store my GIT credentials on Linux:**

Edit `~/.gitconfig` by placing this:

```
[credential]
    helper = store --file /dev/shm/foo
```

the file `/dev/shm/foo` is located on memory and it contains my credentials. It looks something like this:

```
https://MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org
```

I am able to push and pull changes without having to type my password again. When I reboot my computer or when I delete the file `/dev/shm/foo` I am required to enter my password again.

---

### **How can I do the same thing on Windows 10 using Visual Studio?**

I will like to pull and push my changes using Visual Studio. When I attempt to push/pull code visual studio asks me for my credentials by opening a window where I can enter my username and password. If I enter my credentials it works and I am able to push/pull code. **I do not want my credentials to be stored forever though**. When visual studio prompts for the credentials it stores them on `Credential Manager`. I already figured out where is the global .gitconfig file that visual studio uses. It is located at `C:\Users\<MyUser>\.gitconfig`. I have modified that file and placed something like this:

```
[user]
     name = My Name
     email = foo@gmail.com

[credential]
    helper = store --file C:\Users\Antonio\foo.txt
```

where `C:\Users\Antonio\foo.txt` contains the url containing my username and password just like I did with the Linux example that works at the top of this question. When making this changes visual studio shows this error:

> Git failed with a fatal error. fatal: bad config line 6 in file
>   C:/Users/Antonio/.gitconfig

**How can I store my username and password in visual studio so that it gets deleted when I reboot the computer? Moreover, I do not want for the password to be saved on disk just like my linux example where the password is saved on memory**

Comment: Have a look at this. [Always keep a text file in RAM in Windows?](https://superuser.com/a/450722/456779) [The best free RAM Disk programs for Windows](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/04/03/the-best-free-ramdisk-programs-for-windows/)